# multiple jquery fade slideshow with one function using class name

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fadein, fadeout

Ok this may be a noobie question, I hope its easily answered.
I successfully used this simple fade-in fade-out script for a few divs on a page:

```
function fadeContent() {
  $(".banner .picitem:hidden:first").fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
    fadeContent();
  });
}
fadeContent();
```

Problem is now I need it to work for 5 more divs named banner, and it just works for the first one.. I know that some clever use of .each function will work but haven't had much luck!.. any suggestions?

EDIT: I just made a jsfiddle for my problem, in case someone wants to tackle it!.. THNX!
http://jsfiddle.net/perrodeagua/UMua9/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".banner").each(function (index) {
    var $self = $(this).find('.picitem:hidden:first');
    $self.fadeIn(500).delay(5000 * index).fadeOut(500, function () {
        $self.appendTo($self.parent());
    });
});
```

Comment: didn't do it for me either :( after first cycle all my hidden divs appear! here's my url: http://coppelcollection.com/indexNew.php

Comment: EDIT: I just made a jsfiddle for my problem, in case someone wants to tackle it!.. THNX! http://jsfiddle.net/perrodeagua/UMua9/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the selector so all your ".banner" items are included in the selection :

> $(".banner .picitem:hidden:first")

to :

```
$(".banner").find(".picitem:hidden:first")
```

Comment: with this html code, alle my first hidden subElements of .banner were appended to the .banner parent :
<div class="banner">Level1<p class="picitem" style="display:none">Level2 </p><p style="display:none" class="picitem">Level3</p></div>
<div class="banner">Level1<p class="picitem" style="display:none">Level2 </p><p style="display:none" class="picitem">Level3</p></div>
<div class="banner">Level1<p class="picitem" style="display:none">Level2 </p><p style="display:none" class="picitem">Level3</p></div>